# Font which enables to add "\u200e" unicode

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

I need a font which allows to add "\u200e" without displaying any weird characters and will just reverse the text from Left to Right.

For instance:
"\u200e00.1\u200e גירסא"

would display:
"גירסא 1.00"

Comment: I have downloaded dejavu fonts but it still shows the "\u200e"

Answer (score 1):

Including U+200E (LEFT-To-RIGHT MARK) in a font and/or using the character in text does nothing unless the engine/application rendering the text understands what that mark means and applies it correctly (i.e. implements the [Unicode Bi-directional algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/)).